# Unexpected token in view react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I downloaded the Calendar model form [react-native-calendar-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-select)

**Package**

```
npm install --save react-native-calendar-select
```

**Source Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Calendar from 'react-native-calendar-select';


class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date(2017, 6, 12),
            endDate: new Date(2017, 8, 2)
        };
        this.confirmDate = this.confirmDate.bind(this);
        this.openCalendar = this.openCalendar.bind(this);
    }
    // when confirm button is clicked, an object is conveyed to outer component
    // contains following property:
    // startDate [Date Object], endDate [Date Object]
    // startMoment [Moment Object], endMoment [Moment Object]
    confirmDate({ startDate, endDate, startMoment, endMoment }) {
        this.setState({
            startDate,
            endDate
        });
    }
    openCalendar() {
        this.calendar && this.calendar.open();
    }
    // in render function
    render() {
        // It's an optional property, I use this to show the structure of customI18n object.
        let customI18n = {
            'w': ['', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
            'weekday': ['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
            'text': {
                'start': 'Check in',
                'end': 'Check out',
                'date': 'Date',
                'save': 'Confirm',
                'clear': 'Reset'
            },
            'date': 'DD / MM'  // date format
        };
        // optional property, too.
        let color = {
            subColor: '#f0f0f0'
        };
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="Open Calendar" onPress={this.openCalendar} />
                <Calendar
                    i18n="en"
                    ref={(calendar) => { this.calendar = calendar; }}
                    customI18n={customI18n}
                    color={color}
                    format="YYYYMMDD"
                    minDate="20170510"
                    maxDate="20180312"
                    startDate={this.state.startDate}
                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                    onConfirm={this.confirmDate}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

When I run it I get this error
This is the original code from the website I can't find where the problem is

[image: error :emulator]

> it's a calendar date picker, I copied the original code from the [npm
>   website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-select) and placed the code in a class class component
>
> > please can you help me to fix it!

Comment: This is a syntax error. Post the entire code.

Comment: @hongdeveloper hi, I posted the complete code [reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-select)

Comment: missing final '}' in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are two wrong places, firstly, you do not import `Button`, secondly, you copy the example code, but it does not show all code, only constructors and render, so try the following code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Calendar from 'react-native-calendar-select';


class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date(2017, 6, 12),
            endDate: new Date(2017, 8, 2)
        };
        this.confirmDate = this.confirmDate.bind(this);
        this.openCalendar = this.openCalendar.bind(this);
    }
    // when confirm button is clicked, an object is conveyed to outer component
    // contains following property:
    // startDate [Date Object], endDate [Date Object]
    // startMoment [Moment Object], endMoment [Moment Object]
    confirmDate({ startDate, endDate, startMoment, endMoment }) {
        this.setState({
            startDate,
            endDate
        });
    }
    openCalendar() {
        this.calendar && this.calendar.open();
    }
    // in render function
    render() {
        // It's an optional property, I use this to show the structure of customI18n object.
        let customI18n = {
            'w': ['', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
            'weekday': ['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
            'text': {
                'start': 'Check in',
                'end': 'Check out',
                'date': 'Date',
                'save': 'Confirm',
                'clear': 'Reset'
            },
            'date': 'DD / MM'  // date format
        };
        // optional property, too.
        let color = {
            subColor: '#f0f0f0'
        };
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="Open Calendar" onPress={this.openCalendar} />
                <Calendar
                    i18n="en"
                    ref={(calendar) => { this.calendar = calendar; }}
                    customI18n={customI18n}
                    color={color}
                    format="YYYYMMDD"
                    minDate="20170510"
                    maxDate="20180312"
                    startDate={this.state.startDate}
                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                    onConfirm={this.confirmDate}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but I'm still getting the same "invariant violation" error

Comment: @Venda, I do in snack, it is correct. see this link(https://snack.expo.io/@rns/calendar), you should reload the project.

Comment: @Venda, you don't use `icon`, please remove it. it may be your `react-native-vector-icons` not  link

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error, because you are missing last '}'. Just check your code: you open and close your render method, but your class is still open.

Also you import ActionButton but use just Button instead.

The full code shoud look like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Calendar from 'react-native-calendar-select';


class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date(2017, 6, 12),
      endDate: new Date(2017, 8, 2)
    };
    this.confirmDate = this.confirmDate.bind(this);
    this.openCalendar = this.openCalendar.bind(this);
  }

  // when confirm button is clicked, an object is conveyed to outer component
  // contains following property:
  // startDate [Date Object], endDate [Date Object]
  // startMoment [Moment Object], endMoment [Moment Object]
  confirmDate({startDate, endDate, startMoment, endMoment}) {
    this.setState({
      startDate,
      endDate
    });
  }

  openCalendar() {
    this.calendar && this.calendar.open();
  }

  // in render function
  render() {
    // It's an optional property, I use this to show the structure of customI18n object.
    let customI18n = {
      'w': ['', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      'weekday': ['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
      'text': {
        'start': 'Check in',
        'end': 'Check out',
        'date': 'Date',
        'save': 'Confirm',
        'clear': 'Reset'
      },
      'date': 'DD / MM'  // date format
    };
    // optional property, too.
    let color = {
      subColor: '#f0f0f0'
    };
    return (
      <View>
        <ActionButton
          buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)"
          onPress={this.openCalendar}
        />
        <Calendar
          i18n="en"
          ref={(calendar) => {this.calendar = calendar;}}
          customI18n={customI18n}
          color={color}
          format="YYYYMMDD"
          minDate="20170510"
          maxDate="20180312"
          startDate={this.state.startDate}
          endDate={this.state.endDate}
          onConfirm={this.confirmDate}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: **Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in "components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."
I get this can you help

Comment: You import ActionButton, but you use just some unknown Button component in render method. Consider to replace Button by ActionButton.

Comment: @Venda I updated the answer, so you can just copy the code.

Answer (score 0):

when you miss to end bracket or extra brackets then this type of error will generating so press ctrl+shift+f to format the code in visual code to see missing brackets.